# Find the 4 roots of the equation: $z^{4}+4=0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

Find the 4 roots of the equation: $z^{4}+4=0$

**Note: I can't use the form: $e^{i\theta}$**

## **My attempt:**

Note we have: $z=(-4)^{\frac{1}{4}}$, consider $w=-4$, then $w^{1/4}=z$ this implies $w=z^4$.

Consider the polar form of $z$ and $w$:
$|w|=r=4$,
$Arg(w)=\pi=\theta$

Then, 
$$w=4\cos\pi+i\sin\pi$$
$$z=p\cos\phi+i\sin\phi$$

This implies: $w=z^4$ iff $4=p^4$ and $4\phi=\pi+2k\pi$ iff $p=4^{1/4}$ and $\phi=\frac{\pi+2k\pi}{4}$ with $k=0,1,2,3$

Then the roots are:

$$z_k=4^{1/4}(\cos{\frac{\pi+2k\pi}{4}}+i\sin{\frac{\pi+2k\pi}{4}})$$
with $k=0,1,2,3$

is correct this?

Comment: Factor:(z^2-2z+2)(z^2+2z+2)  solving quadratics is so much easier

Comment: You said that "I can't use the form $e^{i\theta}$". But why you "Consider the polar form"? And for "I can't", do you mean you are not able to use it or you are not allowed to?

Comment: I can use the polar form, but not the euler form. @Jack

Comment: I don't understand. The expression $re^{i\theta}$ *is* the polar form of a complex number.  What do you mean by "Euler form"?

Comment: I guess you call $z=re^{i\theta}$ the "Euler form" and $z=r(\cos\theta+i\sin\theta)$ the "polar form"? Is that what you mean?

Comment: Yes exactly, @Jack. Thanks for answer!

Comment: Can I ask what methods you used to get the part "Then the roots are ..."? Did you use the [De Moivre's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Moivre%27s_formula) or something else?

Comment: What he means is that polar form comes from sohcahtoa, meaning trig. For DeMoivre you can avoid e power notation,  as we do when teaching this topic in pre calculus  course

Comment: @Jack, Yes i used Moivre formula for obtain that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You solution looks OK; the writing can be improved slightly though. I will follow your argument and rewrite it as follows.

The equation is equivalent to $z^4=-4$.

Now let $z=r(\cos \theta+i\sin\theta)$ and write 
$$
-4=4(\cos \pi +i\sin \pi)\tag{1}
$$
By the [De Moivre's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Moivre%27s_formula), 
$$
z^4=r^4(\cos (4\theta)+i\sin (4\theta))\tag{2}
$$
Comparing (1) and (2), we have
$$
r=\sqrt[4]{4},\quad 4\theta=(2k+1)\pi,\quad k\in\mathbb{Z}.
$$

Thus the four roots are
$$
z_k=4^{1/4}(\cos{\frac{\pi+2k\pi}{4}}+i\sin{\frac{\pi+2k\pi}{4}})$$
with $k=0,1,2,3$.

---

[Added:] The solution can be simplified further:

- Observe that $4^{1/4}=2^{2/4}=\sqrt{2}$.
- The expression $\cos{\frac{\pi+2k\pi}{4}}+i\sin{\frac{\pi+2k\pi}{4}}$ can be found exactly by hand and thus can be used to simply the solution. For instance, 
  $$
  z_0=\sqrt{2}(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}+i\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2})=1+i.
  $$
  I will leave the cases $k=1,2,3$ to you.

Comment: Thanks for that Jack, Excellent answer!

Comment: @Bvss12: You are welcome! Thanks for providing more context in comments under your post.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the factorization of $z^4+4$:
$$z^4+4=z^4\color{blue}{+4z^2}+4\color{blue}{-4z^2}=(z^2+2)^2-(2z)^2=(z^2+2z+2)(z^2-2z-2)$$
Then we get $z^2+2z+2=0$ or $z^2-2z+2=0$, then finish it by using quadratic formula.

Answer (score 1):

It is $$(z^2)^2+(2^2)^2=0$$ or $$a^2+b^2=0$$ and this is $$(a-bi)(a+bi)=0$$ where $$a=z^2,b=2^2$$

Answer (score 1):

$z^2=\pm 2i$ and then the roots are $\pm1\pm i$.

Comment: The first step is obvious,  but the last step, any teacher might want to see elaboration

Comment: $(1\pm i)^2=\pm 2i$

Comment: You are right, but that is not obvious for the casual observer.